# Como filtrar informações ao carregar um arquivo local?

Tags: mysql

Existe alguma forma de ignorar uma determinada informação ao carregar um arquivo local no MySQL?

Exemplo: Tenho um arquivo de 2 colunas: "TELEFONE" e "VALIDADO". A coluna "VALIDADO" possui os valores 'SIM' e  'NAO'.

[image: Dados da Tabel]

Como não preciso dos casos negativos queria ignorá-los para poupar espaço e diminuir o tempo de consulta na tabela.

Existe alguma maneira de carregar somente os telefones com `VALIDADO = 'SIM'`?

Comment: como você importa esse aquivo?

Comment: Importo via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: Hi Anthony, sorry for the delay.

Yes, I did the test and managed to filter only the YES Status by doing the process you indicated.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode importar todos os dados para uma tabela temporária e então copiar apenas as entradas desejadas para a tabela destino.

Exemplo assumindo uma tabela chamada `contatos`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE contatos_temp LIKE contatos;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'meu_arquivo' INTO TABLE contatos_temp;
INSERT INTO contatos (telefone, validado, dt_imp)
SELECT telefone, validado, dt_imp
  FROM contatos_temp 
 WHERE validado = 'SIM';
-- Opcional se você pretende manter a sessão aberta
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE contatos_temp;
```